# Counter variable not updated

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to write a script to automate the pulling, rendering and pushing of a LaTeX document from/to a repo. The pulling/pushing is no problem, but in order to begin the rendering I would like to check if `.tex` files have changed since the last update (variable `oldHash` holds the info). The problem is that when I execute the code, the counter variable gets reset to 0 once the loop exits. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

##### PULL FROM THE REPO AND SAVE THE HASH #####

# Get the diff between the two commits
diffFiles=$(git diff --name-only "$oldHash" HEAD@{0})

# The commmand produces the following output:
# Chapters/Chapter6.tex
# Other/CustomEnvironments.tex
# RawMaterial/LinearAlgebraNotes_4.pdf
# buildAll.sh
# main.tex

numberOfTexFiles=0

# Loop through every line of the output and strip the files from their extension
printf %s "$diffFiles" | while IFS= read -r line
do
    baseName=$(basename "$line")
    extension="${baseName##*.}"
    if [[ "$extension" == 'tex' ]]; then
        # If the file is a Tex, update the counter
        numberOfTexFiles=$(($numberOfTexFiles+1))
        echo $numberOfTexFiles
    fi
done

echo $numberOfTexFiles

if [ $numberOfTexFiles -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "FILES HAVE CHANGED"
    # Run some other stuff (namely pdflatex)
else
    echo "NOTHING CHANGED"
fi
```

What now happens is that the last if statements evaluate to false, and the `pdflatex` command never gets called. How can I fix it?

## EDIT

As suggested by JID, the redirect was all that I needed. This is my solution:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    baseName=$(basename "$line")
    extension="${baseName##*.}"
    if [[ "$extension" == 'tex' ]]; then
        # If the file is a Tex, update the counter
        numberOfTexFiles=$(($numberOfTexFiles+1))
        echo $numberOfTexFiles
    fi
done <<< $(printf %s "$diffFiles")
```

Comment: don't pipe into a while loop use `done < (command)` instead of `command | while` . This has been asked countless times. search `bash while loop scope` in google for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
if [[ "$extension" == 'tex' ]];
```

My guess is semicolon at the end of if might be causing this issue. Could you please remove that and see if it works?

Comment: Semicolon *is* required because `then` follows it.